# Java algorithm to put land coordinates to Google map format

Tags: java, google-maps

I have some static land coordinates and i want put or transform these values into to Google map format *(include supporting  zoom levels and optimal pixel position for performance)*.

Can be any advice for suitable *algorithm* in JAVA for processing of this solution?

For any helpfully suggestion i will appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest writing a routine in Java that would transform your data into KML. KML is an XML based syntax for representing geolocation information  https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/ Once it is KML, you can load it into either Google earth or Google maps directly.

There is a java API that should help facilitate this translation: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/thlandgraf/archive/2009/08/java_api_for_km.html